# Binding kendo grid to dropdownlist, column displays 'undefined' when not populated

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

I seem to be having a unique issue in my kendo grid.  I have searched everywhere and tried multiple things but no luck.  I need to bind my "HoldReason" dropdownlist to the kendo grid and the "HoldReason" will always be null or nothing selected initially.  Currently my grid shows 'undefined' in that grid column.

ViewModel:

```
  public class PaymentDetailTerm
  {
    public PaymentDetailTerm()
    {
    }

    private int? holdReasonId;
    private bool holdFlag;
    private decimal disbursed;
    private SysHoldReason holdReason;

    //some properties omitted 

    [Display(Name = "Disbursed")]
    [NonNegative]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal Disbursed
    {
      get
      {
        return disbursed;
      }
      set
      {
        disbursed = value;
      }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Hold")]
    [BoolFieldRequiredWhenInt("HoldReasonId")]
    public bool HoldFlag
    {
      get
      {
        return holdFlag;
      }
      set
      {
        holdFlag = value;
      }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Hold Reason")]
    [IDFieldRequiredWhenBool("HoldFlag")]
    public int? HoldReasonId
    {
      get
      {
        return holdReasonId;
      }
      set
      {
        holdReasonId = value;
      }
    }

    [UIHint("HoldReasonEditor")]
    public SysHoldReason HoldReason
    {
      get
      {
        if (holdReason == null || holdReason.HoldReasonId == 0)
        {
          return new SysHoldReason() { HoldReasonId = 0, HoldReasonTitle = string.Empty };
        }
        else return holdReason;
      }
      set { holdReason = value; }   
    }
}
```

TemplateEditor "HoldReasonEditor":

```
  @using System.Collections
  @using Kendo.Mvc.UI


<kendo-dropdownlist name="HoldReasonId" bind-to="ViewBag.HoldReasonId" Auto-Width="true" option-label=" " datatextfield="Text" datavaluefield="Value" value-primitive="true"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Controller (these are the only two statements concerning the dropdown in question):

```
  ViewData["HoldReasonId"] = new SelectList(_context.SysHoldReason.Where<SysHoldReason>(x => x.SiteId == 99 || x.SiteId == _user.SiteId), "HoldReasonId", "HoldReasonTitle");
  ViewData["HoldReasonCollection"] = new SelectList(_context.SysHoldReason.Where<SysHoldReason>(x => x.SiteId == 99 || x.SiteId == _user.SiteId), "HoldReasonId", "HoldReasonTitle");
```

I use the HoldReasonCollection as a hidden field so I can set the information correctly later on grid save.  SysHoldReason model contains HoldReasonId and HoldReasonTitle properties (and more, but those are the only ones I'm concerned with).

And the kendo grid defined in my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<eCLERC.ViewModels.PaymentDetailTerm>(Model.PaymentDetailTerms)
  .Name("TermGrid")
  .DataSource(ds => ds
  .Ajax()
  .ServerOperation(false)
  .Model(m =>
  {
    m.Field(d => d.TermTypeTitle).Editable(false);
    m.Field(d => d.PayeePartyName).Editable(false);
    m.Field(d => d.PayoffBalance).Editable(false);
    m.Field(d => d.PeriodicAmount).Editable(false);
    m.Field(d => d.UnpaidBalance).Editable(false);
    m.Field(d => d.ClerkFeeFlag).Editable(false);
    m.Field(d => d.HoldFlag).Editable(true);
    m.Field(d => d.HoldReasonId).Editable(true);
    m.Field(d => d.HoldReason);
    //m.Field(p => p.HoldReason).DefaultValue(ViewData["HoldReasonId"] as eCLERC.Models.DB.SysHoldReason);
  })
  )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(e => e.TermTypeTitle).Width(110).Title("Term Type");
    columns.Bound(e => e.PayeePartyName).Width(110).Title("Payee");
    columns.Bound(e => e.PayoffBalance).Width(110);
    columns.Bound(e => e.PeriodicAmount).Width(110); //TODO: Nikki - what is recap amount
    columns.Bound(e => e.UnpaidBalance).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(e => e.ClerkFeeFlag).Width(100);

    columns.Bound(e => e.Disbursed).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(e => e.HoldFlag).Width(100);
    columns.Bound(e => e.HoldReason).EditorTemplateName("HoldReasonEditor").ClientTemplate("#=HoldReason.Text#");
  })
  .Sortable()
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
  .Events(x => { x.Save("function(e){onGridSave(e)}"); })
  .Scrollable()
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:350px" }))
```

The dropdown works and if I select a value, then I see the HoldReason title value as I expect to, but I just can't figure out how to fix the 'undefined' text that shows initially.  And likewise, if I want to set the dropdown back to the option label (" "), the dropdown control shows a validation that HoldReasonId required.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!! So, I figured this out.  First, the HoldReasonId required error.  I was binding that control to a database model for the whole code table, id, title, description, etc.  This was also the model that controlled the data entry for that code table, so the id value was required, which was why I was getting that error.  It was giving me the validation from the SysHoldReason database model.  I fixed this by creating a separate view model, for ViewSysHoldReason, which only contains a nullable HoldReasonId value and a string HoldReasonTitle value.

```
  public class ViewSysHoldReason
  {
    public int? HoldReasonId { get; set; }
    public string HoldReasonTitle { get; set; }
  }
```

Next, I updated my PaymentDetailTerm view model to use this for the editor instead of the whole code table database model as before.

```
public class PaymentDetailTerm
  {
    public PaymentDetailTerm()
    {
    }

    private int? holdReasonId;
    private bool holdFlag;
    private decimal disbursed;
    private ViewSysHoldReason viewSysHoldReason;

    //some properties omitted 

    [Display(Name = "Disbursed")]
    [NonNegative]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
    public decimal Disbursed
    {
      get
      {
        return disbursed;
      }
      set
      {
        disbursed = value;
      }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Hold")]
    [BoolFieldRequiredWhenInt("HoldReasonId")]
    public bool HoldFlag
    {
      get
      {
        return holdFlag;
      }
      set
      {
        holdFlag = value;
      }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Hold Reason")]
    [IDFieldRequiredWhenBool("HoldFlag")]
    public int? HoldReasonId
    {
      get
      {
        return holdReasonId;
      }
      set
      {
        holdReasonId = value;
      }
    }

    [UIHint("HoldReasonEditor")]
    public ViewSysHoldReason HoldReason
    {
      get
      {
        if (viewSysHoldReason == null || viewSysHoldReason.HoldReasonId == 0)
        {
          return new ViewSysHoldReason() { HoldReasonId = 0, HoldReasonTitle = string.Empty };
        }
        else return viewSysHoldReason;
      }
      set { viewSysHoldReason = value; }
    }
}
```

The last property above for HoldReason is all that changed here.  Next, I updated the grid for display as shown here:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<eCLERC.ViewModels.PaymentDetailTerm>(Model.PaymentDetailTerms)
      .Name("TermGrid")
      .DataSource(ds => ds
      .Ajax()
      .ServerOperation(false)
      .Model(m =>
      {
        m.Field(d => d.TermTypeTitle).Editable(false);
        m.Field(d => d.PayeePartyName).Editable(false);
        m.Field(d => d.PayoffBalance).Editable(false);
        m.Field(d => d.PeriodicAmount).Editable(false);
        m.Field(d => d.UnpaidBalance).Editable(false);
        m.Field(d => d.ClerkFeeFlag).Editable(false);
        m.Field(d => d.HoldFlag).Editable(true);
        m.Field(d => d.HoldReasonId).Editable(true);
        m.Field(d => d.HoldReason);
      })
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
        columns.Bound(e => e.TermTypeTitle).Width(110).Title("Term Type");
        columns.Bound(e => e.PayeePartyName).Width(110).Title("Payee");
        columns.Bound(e => e.PayoffBalance).Width(110);
        columns.Bound(e => e.PeriodicAmount).Width(110); //TODO: Nikki - what is recap amount
        columns.Bound(e => e.UnpaidBalance).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(e => e.ClerkFeeFlag).Width(100);

        columns.Bound(e => e.Disbursed).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(e => e.HoldFlag).Width(100);
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.HoldReason, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["HoldReasonId"], "Value", "Text")
          .EditorViewData(new {HoldReasonId = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["HoldReasonId"]})
          .EditorTemplateName("HoldReasonEditor").ClientTemplate("#=HoldReason.Value > 0 ? HoldReason.Text : '' #")
          .Title("Hold Reason")
          .Width(110);
      })
      .Sortable()
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Events(x => { x.Save("function(e){onGridSave(e)}"); x.CellClose("function(e){onCellClose(e)}"); })
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:350px" }))
```

Note that I added an event for CellClose.  This is because I wanted to catch the editor when a user selected the optionlabel = " " to remove a HoldReason from the grid.  I could not figure out how to set that value back to empty once a user selected a value from the dropdown, so the CellClose was my solution to that.

```
function onCellClose(e) {
    var grid = $("#TermGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var fieldName = grid.columns[e.container.index()].field;

    if (fieldName == "HoldReason" && e.container.find("input").val() == "") {
      e.model.HoldReasonId = 0;
      e.model.HoldReason.Value = 0;
      e.model.HoldReason.Text = "";
    }
  }
```

The model would not be set correctly without the onGridSave event though so I feel like I should show that code as well.  I did not share it on my original post.

```
function onGridSave(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var grid = $("#TermGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var fieldName = grid.columns[e.container.index()].field;

    if (fieldName == "HoldReason") {
      $('#HoldReasonCollection').data('kendoDropDownList').value(e.container.find("input").val());
      e.model.HoldReasonId = e.values["HoldReason.HoldReasonId"];
      e.model.HoldReason = $('#HoldReasonCollection').data('kendoDropDownList').dataItem();
    }
    if (fieldName == "Disbursed") {
      e.model.Disbursed = e.container.find("input").val();
    }
    if (fieldName == "HoldFlag" && e.model.HoldFlag == true) {
      e.model.HoldFlag = false;
    }
    else if (fieldName == "HoldFlag" && e.model.HoldFlag == false) {
      e.model.HoldFlag = true;
    }
  }
```